# Filter items with Django Query

Tags: django, algorithm, orm, filter

I'm encountering this problem and would like to seek your help.

The context: 
I'm having a bag of balls, each of which has an age (red and blue) and color attributes.

What I want is to get the top 10 "youngest" balls and there are at most 3 blue balls (this means if there are more than 3 blue balls in the list of 10 youngest balls, then replace the "redudant" oldest blue balls with the youngest red balls)

To get top 10:

```
sel_balls = Ball.objects.all().sort('age')[:10]
```

Now, to also satisfy the conditions "at most 3 blue balls", I need to process further:

1. Iterate through sel_balls and count the number of blue balls (= B)
2. If B <= 3: do nothing
3. Else: get additional B - 3 red balls to replace the oldest (B - 3) blue balls (and these red balls must not have appeared in the original 10 balls already taken out). I figure I can do this by getting the oldest age value among the list of red balls and do another query like:

   add_reds = Ball.objects.filter(age >= oldest_sel_age)[: B - 3]

My question is:

1. Is there any way that I can satisfy the constraints in only one query?
2. If I have to do 2 queries, is there any faster ways than the one method I mentioned above?

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you try the classmethod function under model? You can do your logic there and you can call it like this in your view, `sel_balls = Ball.sort_balls`

Answer (score 0):

Use Q for complex queries to the database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

You should use annotate to do it.
See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

`.filter()` before `.annotate()` gives 'WHERE'

`.filter()` after `.annotate()` gives 'HAVING' (this is what you need)